# Couldn't update When I use Visual Studio Installer to update new version (for example 15.7.* to 15.9.* or up to now)

Tags: visual-studio

It can't install when I use Visual Studio Installer to update the new version (for example 15.7.* to 15.9.*).
The errors message shows  the **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Msi"** isn't installed by some reason

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer now, please follow the steps to fix this issue.

PS: I think not only it can fix the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Interop.Msi" but it can fix other problems when you update some packages(resources) with the same steps

Step1
Download and install the  Microsoft support tool [URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed)
[image]

Step2
Open it and pick the **vs_minshellinteropmsi** out 
[image]

Step3
Reinstall Visual Studio Installer again 
[image]

[Mandarin reference](http://marcus116.blogspot.com/2019/04/visualstudio-visual-studio-2019-install-error-minshellinteropmsi.html)