# Visual Studio 2019 Installation can't get past package Microsoft.VisualStduio.MinShell.Msi.Resources

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019

Every time I try to install Visual Studio 2019, I get the error

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.Resources could not be installed.

I have tried everything I have found on the Internet. When I go to the Download folder of the Visual Studio Installer and I execute the .msi file directly of the package I get the error that it is forbidden due to a software group policy. It is my laptop and I am the admin, so there is no reason why it should be forbidden. I have Windows 10 Home and I am trying to install Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise(the Community edition also does not work).

Here is the Link to my Log files:
[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QI6HsOnxrlBQjO0D1MBxwR7HO8pjLDwA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778820/couldnt-update-when-i-use-visual-studio-installer-to-update-new-version-for-ex This method worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following suggestions:

**1)** delete any files under `%Temp%`

**2)** Check if there have 3rd party anti-virus software enabled or enterprise group policy in place that is restricting you or not.

**3)** type `Administrative Tools` in Windows search box - Open `Local Security Settings` -- `Software Restriction Policies` ( **Note**: If no software restrictions are defined, right click the `Software Restriction Policies` node and select `New Software Restriction Policy`) - Double click **Enforcement** - Select `All users except Local Administrators` - Click **OK** - Restart the computer for the changes to take effect.

**4)** enter **Manage User Certificates** under Search Box-->**Untrusted Certificates**-->remove any info about **Microsoft**.

enter

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.Resources,version=16.0.xxx.xxx` and right-click on the folder-->Security--> make sure your current user account has the right to modify the folder.

**Then**, run `VS_Installer` as **Administrator**

**5) Besides**, if it does not help, please run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe` to reinstall the whole VS(all versions of `VS2017` and `VS2019`), vs data, related registry information(do a deep uninstallation), then run `vs_installer` as **Administrator** to try again.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen to me on the Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNetPackages.Msi package.
I found this [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/2742).

They suggested to find the MSI in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages` directory and run it while the installer is paused. Then resume the install. This worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure that is the link that suggested that? The suggestion you reference is not mentioned anywhere in that GitHub issue. Are you perhaps thinking of this link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1098745/cant-install-visual-studio-due-to-microsoft-visual?orderby=newest

Comment: ugg, i don't know now. it has been too long ago

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when installing...
I was able to get passed it, it is a bug in Windows 10...

Open up Settings -> Update and Security -> Then go down to Developer Mode which allows you to install from any source even if it is trusted...

Then run the installer...

You can turn off Developer Mode afterwards.

Comment: If you're a developer you should just leave developer mode on all the time.