# VsWebProtocolSelector.Msi won't listen new Shared Installation Path

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I try desperately to find an answer [to the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190561/failed-to-install-microsoft-visualstudio-vswebprotocolselector-msi-resources-pac) I started few months ago.

Here is the issue :
I can't install Visual Studio (any version) anymore because the package windows installer (.msi) do not want to listen to the shared installation path that has been changed in the registry editor at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\Setup\\SharedInstallationPath`.
You'll understand with these 2 screenshots :

Here is the SharedInstallationPath I updated to test:

[image: Here is the SharedInstallationPath I updated to test]

Here is the response after I changed the path:

[image: Here is the response after I changed the path]

Which is the same as before I changed. It's been a year now since I had this issue. There's nothing I can do to make `VsWebProtocolSelector` to change the path of the shared files.
Is there anyway I can change this path (by the registry editor maybe)?
You can find the file on your computer at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsWebProtocolSelector.Msi,version=17.4.33006.217`

Does someone know what can I do?

[Edit] Update : I just wipe my HDD's partitions and re-install windows with a new Visual Studio Community 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to copy/paste the package from another pc with vs studio installed?

Comment: No but it won't works as the path will not be the same, and I can't make it to update the changes

Comment: I still can't make it works tho, I'm starting to lose hope :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. I searched the registry for `VsWebProtocolSelector` and found some installation data at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\6957A9C67E8C0B445B1C515DBC7994A9\InstallProperties`. In there was a value named `UninstallString`. I promptly executed it:

```
MsiExec.exe /I{6C9A7596-C8E7-44B0-B5C1-15D5CB97499A}
```

Afterwards, the Visual Studio Setup involving VsWebProtocolSelector  suceeded.

Note: This answer probably does the same thing: [Couldn't update When I use Visual Studio Installer to update new version (for example 15.7.* to 15.9.* or up to now)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778820/couldnt-update-when-i-use-visual-studio-installer-to-update-new-version-for-ex)